# Server Crashes when a client closes the program

Tags: c#, serversocket

I have program that several clients can connect to at the same time.

When you send the time, it gives you the time, But when one of the clients exits the program, the software crashes!

Server source code:

```
static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
static List<Socket> clinetSockets = new List<Socket>();
static byte[] buffer = new byte[119];

static void Main(string[] args){
    Console.Title = "server";
    SetupServer();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void SetupServer(){
    Console.WriteLine("Setting up server . . .");
    serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 100));
    serverSocket.Listen(10);
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
}

static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult ar){
    Socket socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);
    Console.WriteLine("Client Connected: " + socket.LocalEndPoint);
    clinetSockets.Add(socket);
    socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReciveCallBack), socket);
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
}

static void ReciveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar) {
    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    int recived = socket.EndReceive(ar);
    byte[] dataBuf = new byte[recived];
    Array.Copy(buffer, dataBuf, recived);
    string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
    string responce;
    if (text.ToLower() == "time")
        responce = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    else
        responce = "Invalid Requist";
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responce);
    socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), socket);
    socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReciveCallBack), socket);
}

static void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar){
    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    socket.EndSend(ar);
}
```

How can I close the client thread and what other code is needed?

Comment: You don't check if `received` is zero, which is your first problem. The next is that you seem to assume that you'll be getting *messages*. There is no guarantee that a call to `Send` at one end will be matched 1-1 with a call to `Receive` at the other end. You might receive e.g. `ti` in one receive call and `me` in the next.

Comment: still crash! crash when received! 

i tried with ```try {} catch {}``` it works!